# replacing words in a web page with JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I was trying to make a Firefox extension that filters out cuss words and as a test I made it try to filter out the word "the" and replace it with "!@#$", but when I ran it nothing happened I have no clue why. Could someone help? here's my code:

```
function replaceText(selector, text, newText, flags) {
  var matcher = new RegExp(text, flags);
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector), i;

  for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
    if (!elems[i].childNodes.length)
      elems[i].innerHTML = elems[i].innerHTML.replace(matcher, newText);
}

var selectorsToUse = ["p", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "a", ];
var curseWords= [["the" "!@#$"]]

for(curseRegex = 0; curseRegex < curseWords.length; curseRegex++;)
{
    for(i = 0; i < selectorsToUse.length; i++)
    {
        replaceText(selectorstouse[i], cursewords[curseregex][0],
        curseWords[curseRegex][1], "gi");
    };
};
```

I used someone else's code for the function by the way

Comment: You have multiple syntax errors in this, e.g. `;` in your `for` loop, and `selectorstouse` instead of `selectorsToUse`. Try fixing those first :)

Comment: Missing a comma in `curseWords = [["the" /* comma should be here */ "!@#$"]]`, too

Answer (score 1):

All that code seems like a bit more work than is necessary.  Try something simpler with a regular expression.  For example, `/the/ig`.  The expression (just a word in this case) is written between the forward slashes.  The little `i` is for case insensitive, so "the", "THE", "The", and any other combination will always be matched.  The little `g` is for global, so you can get ALL instances of "the" in the current string.  In the event that you want to add more words, just add a `|` plus the next word, like `/the|dog/ig`.  This can go on for as many words as you want. `/the|dog|cow|cat/ig`

Try this:

```
const curses = /the/ig
const filterStr = '!@#$'
const selectors = ['p', 'h1', 'a']

selectors.forEach(selector => {
  const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)] //convert node list to array
  elements.forEach(el =>
    el.textContent = el.textContent.replace(curses, filterStr))
})
```

Or ES5 if you prefer:

```
var curses = /the/ig;
var filterStr = '!@#$';
var selectors = ['p', 'h1', 'a'];

selectors.forEach( function(selector) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements); //convert node list to array
  elements.forEach( function(el) {
    el.textContent = el.textContent.replace(curses, filterStr);
  })
})
```

Have a look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pKKyzP) to play 
around with it.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help

Comment: If this solved your issue, would you accept this answer? It would help me out a bit. ;)

Comment: sorry for bothering you but with the code you gave me I have to reload the page sometimes for it to load this happens on Reddit when I click on a post not sure if it happens anywhere else do you know why?

Comment: I have a hunch that reddit is loading content dynamically.  This code will run once on page load, but if something is loaded in after the initial load, it won't affect that.  It may be pretty difficult to make your code react to any ajax call universally, but one workaround you could potentially do is continuously run the code on a loop.  Just be careful with that because loops can be pretty slow if you add too much.

Comment: Assuming you wrap all the code above in a function called `filterCurses()` try `setInterval(filterCurses, 500)`